# Mouse curser follow parallax effect on an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want these images to display when hovering over the title in addition to that when I hover and move my cursor around the title I want the image to follow the cursor. I am new to JavaScript, any help from you guys would be much appreciated.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.manImg {
  display: none;
}

.manImg2 {
  display: none;
}

.hover-text {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: 3px;
  font-family: Odachi;
}

.hover-text:hover {
  color: red;
}

.hover-text:hover~.manImg2 {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://awallpaperaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/orange-cliffs-1920x1080-1860x1046.jpg) center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -9999999999;
}

.hover-text:hover~.manImg {
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.1084082127f8d9d45194657db272109e?rik=6tKaSe%2b57Mvvkg&riu=http%3a%2f%2fimages.freehdw.com%2f510%2f3d-abstract_widewallpaper_fulfill-wish_50806.jpg&ehk=Tlkf5BUKl0223C4FgHOuHAHIe5tedec%2bWhkhyj5tHyI%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -9999999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-jamf" id="module-jamf">

  <a class="jamf-container" id="jamf-container" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <center>
      <p class="hover-text">TITLE1</p>
      <img id="new" class="manImg" src="">
      <div class="jamf-mover" id="jamf-mover">
      </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="module-jamf" id="module-jamf">

  <a class="jamf-container" id="jamf-container" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <center>
      <p class="hover-text">TITLE2</p>
      <img id="new" class="manImg2" src="">
      <div class="jamf-mover" id="jamf-mover">
      </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want these images to display when hovering over the title in addition to that when I hover and move my cursor around the title I want the image to follow the cursor. I am new to JavaScript, any help from you guys would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you show us some code you have tried, or a jsfiddle, or a codepen example?

Comment: Hey, I wasn't able to insert the code. Now I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you bind to the mousemove event on the document and then use that to track the mouse x and y position, then translate that value to the background position of said images, just add the below javascript to your page (at the end of the document in `script` tag after the jquery js library import)

## Code

I'm using the latest version of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$(document).on('mousemove', (e)=>{
    let el = $('.manImg'); 
    el.css({"background-position": (el.width() + e.offsetX) + "px " + (el.height() + e.offsetY) +  "px"});
    let el2 = $('.manImg2'); 
    el2.css({"background-position": (el2.width() + e.offsetX) + "px " + (el2.height() + e.offsetY) +  "px"});
});
```

## Example

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sjf3hr15/1/) is a jsFiddle Example

## Edit 1

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Dean, thanks a lot for the solution. But I think this isn't working. I am using WordPress and have added HTML element to it and used this code in one element. javascript and css in <head> and rest in <body>

Comment: I found that it is working fine on jsFiddle but when I try to copy the same code and run it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArchiesShedge please add jquery to your wordpress in the head, see my edit

Comment: that script tag must be added before the the code i posted